# Auto Fill calendar with missing months

Tags: python, pandas, date, automation, autofill

I have a table like this with date and values but, as you can see, some months are not in the list. (5, 6, 8, 10 and 1 from the next year).

| Date | Any other value |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | value |
| 2020-02-01 | value |
| 2020-02-04 | value |
| 2020-02-04 | value |
| 2020-03-11 | value |
| 2020-04-04 | value |
| 2020-07-04 | value |
| 2020-07-04 | value |
| 2020-09-01 | value |
| 2020-11-06 | value |
| 2020-12-02 | value |
| 2021-02-04 | value |
| 2021-03-11 | value |

Is any way that I can automatically fill this table with those months, to become?

| Date | Any other value |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | value |
| 2020-02-01 | value |
| 2020-02-04 | value |
| 2020-02-04 | value |
| 2020-03-11 | value |
| 2020-04-04 | value |
| 2020-05-01 | **NaN** |
| 2020-06-01 | **NaN** |
| 2020-07-04 | value |
| 2020-07-04 | value |
| 2020-08-01 | **NaN** |
| 2020-09-01 | value |
| 2020-10-01 | **NaN** |
| 2020-11-06 | value |
| 2020-12-02 | value |
| 2021-01-01 | **NaN** |
| 2021-02-04 | value |
| 2021-03-11 | value |

Thank to you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logically it's an outer join to all the months you are interested in.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Date":["2019-12-31","2020-01-31","2020-02-03","2020-02-03","2020-03-10","2020-04-03","2020-07-03","2020-07-03","2020-08-31","2020-11-05","2020-12-01","2021-02-03","2021-03-10"],"Any other value":["value","value","value","value","value","value","value","value","value","value","value","value","value"]})
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])

df["month"] = (df['Date'] - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)).dt.floor('d')


df = df.merge(
pd.DataFrame({"month":pd.date_range(df["month"].min(), df["month"].max(), freq="MS")}),
    on="month", how="outer")
df["Date"].fillna(df["month"], inplace=True)
df = df.drop(columns="month")

print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

### output

```
      Date Any other value
2019-12-31           value
2020-01-31           value
2020-02-03           value
2020-02-03           value
2020-03-10           value
2020-04-03           value
2020-07-03           value
2020-07-03           value
2020-08-31           value
2020-11-05           value
2020-12-01           value
2021-02-03           value
2021-03-10           value
2020-05-01             NaN
2020-06-01             NaN
2020-09-01             NaN
2020-10-01             NaN
2020-12-01             NaN
2021-01-01             NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Helped a lot.
I just have one more question, why do you use .dt.floor('d').
What's the difference of not use it?

Comment: In your question you noted you wanted to insert missing months and missing month example are 1st.  So floored to 1st of month so when join is done has expected outcome.  It will be a bit more obvious if you don't drop the working column #month#

Comment: Thanks, Rob.
I didn't drop to see what was going on, but in the data example they gave me the same result, so I came ask.
Thanks a lot, man. Your help was very handy.

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of this:

```
import numpy as np

df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%Y-%m-%d')
df['Date1'] = df['Date']
df = df.set_index('Date').to_period('m')

t2 = (pd.date_range(df.Date1[0], df.Date1[-1],freq='MS'))
t3 = t2.to_period('m')

add_month = []
for i in range(len(t2)):
    if t3[i] not in df.index:
        add_month.append(t2[i])
miss_month_df = pd.DataFrame(add_month, columns=['Date1'])
miss_month_df['Any'] = np.nan
df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)

df_new = pd.concat([df, miss_month_df], ignore_index=True).sort_values(by='Date1').reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

**df_new:**

```
    Any     Date1
0   value   2020-01-01
1   value   2020-02-01
2   value   2020-02-04
3   value   2020-02-04
4   value   2020-03-11
5   value   2020-04-04
6   NaN     2020-05-01
7   NaN     2020-06-01
8   value   2020-07-04
9   value   2020-07-04
10  NaN     2020-08-01
11  value   2020-09-01
12  NaN     2020-10-01
13  value   2020-11-06
14  value   2020-12-02
15  NaN     2021-01-01
16  value   2021-02-04
17  value   2021-03-11
```

Comment: Thanks Pygirl for the answer.
Was a great help.